# How to use inheritance and extendable templates together?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a darts scoring application in Angular.

I have created a GameBaseComponent, which defines basic data structure, some common methods and the basic layout of a darts game.

Now I would like to create new classes for each game type. These should define how a throw is handled, what is the win condition and the layout of settings and results. The former can be achieved by inheritance, and the later can be done by ng-container, but I feel that combining these two is somewhat 'hacky' (I use the component in the template from which I inherit...), and that it should be done somehow else.

You can check the code here: https://github.com/hodossy/darts-scorer/tree/master/src/app/games

Do anybody have a solution for situations like that?

Answer (score 0):

As i know you cannot inherit template on angular but, the component can inherits structure from class.

So your solution is as following:

- If you have shared template between all games component, you should create one base component with the shared template and structure and use router outlet.
- If you have only shared structure, you can create base class and make the components inherit that class, but each component should have it's own template.

Comment: Interesting, I would rather avoid different templates, but could you please give a bit more detail about using router outlets?

Comment: As you can see on the angular documentation, the heroes names list is always there and the content is changeable. Please see the full example on the documentation.    https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Its worth the mention as you can use ng-content also but actually i did not use it before so, i do not have example for it.